# SQL query returning wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

On my site a user can select players out of a squad of 32 players. There are 15 positions in the starting lineup so out of the 32 player squad 15 players need to be selected.

1 Player can play more than one position as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Now when the user selects the starting line up out of the squad a certain players name that can play more than 1 position (as in the image above) needs to show up in both the positions, unfortunately this is not working as you can see in the image below:

[image]

If you look at image 1 you can see Badden Kerr can play both flyhalf and fullback.

**The Problem**

In the select list the secondary position of a player does not show up. As an example If you look at image 1 again you can see Badden Kerr can play both flyhalf and fullback. But in the second image the fullback position is empty and Baden Kerrs name does not appear in his secondary position (fullback)

---

When I run the following sql statment in Phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT *
FROM `allsquads`
WHERE `Team` = 'Blues'
AND `Position` = 'flyhalf'
AND `Secondary` = 'fullback'
```

I get the correct result returned as you can see in the image below:
[image]

However when I try to run the same SQL statment in my PHP code it gives me wrong / undesired results (As you can see in image2)

My PHP code follows:

```
// assign each position to array variable position
        $position = array(
            "prop",
            "hooker",
            "prop",
            "lock",
            "lock",
            "flank",
            "flank",
            "no8",
            "scrumhalf",
            "flyhalf",
            "center",
            "center",
            "wing",
            "wing",
            "fullback"
        );
        // for loop to loop through the number of positions in the team, which will be used to query DB
        $size     = sizeof($position);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
            // Query For positions
            $sqlprops = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `allsquads` 
                                     WHERE `Team` = '$t1select'  
                                     AND `Position` = '$position[$i]' 
                                     OR `Secondary` = '$position[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**New Problem**
When I do the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `allsquads` 
                               WHERE `Team` = '$t1select'  
                                AND `Position` = '$position[$i]' 
                                OR `Secondary` = '$position[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

*The query now show the players in both their positions but it displays other players who is not in the select team?*

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Thank you in advance

Comment: In your query, it would translate to: `SELECT * FROM allsquads 
                                     WHERE Team = '$t1select'  
                                     AND Position = 'flyhalf' 
                                     AND Secondary = 'flyhalf'` , that's the reason it doesn't work

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger any chance you can point me in the right direction with the PHP query

Comment: When I change it to:                 `SELECT * FROM allsquads 
                                     WHERE Team = '$t1select'  
                                     AND Position = 'flyhalf' 
                                     OR Secondary = 'flyhalf'` I get the correct results but then it displays players from other teams aswell...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query in the PHP code won't produce the desired result because you have it setting `Position` and `Secondary` to the same value. Based on the sample data you provided that won't return anything.

If you're looking for a query to select eligible players for the dropdwon you could change the query to look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `allsquads` 
WHERE `Team` = '$t1select'  
AND (`Position` = '$position[$i]' OR `Secondary` = '$position[$i]')
```

Comment: @Durandai thank you for your answer, I just did that but then it returns results from players from other teams aswell....

Comment: @Marilee As long as you still have a `Team` it should filter it to only entries for that team

Comment: @Durandi I know but it does not make sense since it shows players from other teams...

Comment: @Marilee Where does the `$t1select` come from? Another drop down?

Comment: @Durandai Yes $t1select comes from a drop down where you choose the one team and then there is a $t2select where you choose the second team

Comment: @Durandai the problem is it displays in the dropdown players from both $t1select and $t2select

Comment: What does it return if you run this in phpmyadmin: `SELECT *
FROM `allsquads`
WHERE `Team` = 'Blues'
AND (`Position` = 'flyhalf'
OR `Secondary` = 'fullback')`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48217/discussion-between-durandal-and-marilee)

Answer (score 1):

You should optimize your database structure. While there are ways to work around what you've come up with, I think it would be better to normalize your tables so that you have a table of players and a different table that has player IDs and possible positions (if you really care whether it's a primary or secondary position, you can add a field for that as well).

So your `players` table would be

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ player_id ║ player_name ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1         ║ John Doe    ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

Plus more if needed; the rest of your structure isn't clear to me from reading the question. The `positions` table would be:

```
╔═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╗
║ player_id ║ position  ║ role      ║
╠═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1         ║ flyhalf   ║ primary   ║
║ 1         ║ fullback  ║ secondary ║
╚═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╝
```

Then to find all players who play flyhalf, you would query `` select `players`.`player_name` from `players`,`positions` where `positions`.`position` = "flyhalf" and `players`.`player_id`=`position`.`plr_id` ``

Furthermore, you could (and probably should) normalize the position names to another table, so `positions.position` is an integer referencing table `possible_positions`

```
╔════════╦═══════════╗
║ pos_id ║ position  ║
╠════════╬═══════════╣
║ 1      ║ flyhalf   ║
║ 2      ║ fullback  ║
╚════════╩═══════════╝
```

Furthermore, doing that will allow you to keep the list of possible positions in the database and as a database query rather than hardcoding in to the PHP array as you currently do.

At least, that should get you started. Database normalization and having a proper structure from the beginning will probably be a big help to you constructing these queries.