# PHP query giving wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

This is a follow up question on a previous question I asked [SQL query returning wrong results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978905/sql-query-returning-wrong-results)

**Quick Background of Question**

On my site a user can select players out of a squad of 32 players. There are 15 positions in the starting lineup so out of the 32 player squad 15 players need to be selected.
**1 player can play more than one position**

When I run the following PHP query

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `allsquads` WHERE `Team` = '$t1select' 
                    AND `Position` = '$position[$i]' 
                    OR `Secondary` = '$position[$i]'") or die(mysql_error());
```

**The Problem**

The query works but it does not return players from only `$t1select` which is the team the user selected, it displays players from ALL teams in my database.

Any idea how I can fix this or why this is happening.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The (`mysql_*`) extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead,the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used. Switching to `PreparedStatements` is even more better to ward off SQL Injection attacks !

Comment: `Condition AND Condition OR Condition` should be changed to `Condition AND (Condition OR Condition)`

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran thank you for that and I am well aware of the depreciation, however I am still a student and our lecturer instructed us to use (mysql_*) for now

Comment: Bad lecturer in my opinion...

Comment: Why on earth would a teacher force their students to write bad code? Just teach them to do it right in the first place. Sheesh. It's not like you need to learn one to then learn the other.

Comment: @marilee it's "deprecated". It may or may not "depreciate" in consequence.

Answer (score 2):

May be you should write your query like

```
$sql1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `allsquads` WHERE `Team` = '".$t1select."' 
                AND ( `Position` = '$position[$i]' 
                OR `Secondary` = '$position[$i]' ) ") or die(mysql_error());
```

Because your `OR` condition will be between `Position` and `Secondary`.As you have written it will take

```
`Team` = '".$t1select."' AND `Position` = '$position[$i]'
```

And then apply `Or` condition to that result.

**Note :**`mysql` functions are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 so you need to use either of `mysqli` or `PDO` statements.

Answer (score 0):

```
... WHERE Team = '$t1select'
            AND '$position[$i]' IN (Position,Secondary)
```